# How can I make syslog-ng to filter for a user name?

Tags: logs, syslog, syslog-ng

I've found a nice feature of the syslog-ng: if I use the [logger](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) to log things from the user process, I get the logging user name. Around so:

```
peterh$ echo test log message|logger
```

then I get this in `/var/log/messages`:

```
Oct 12 16:38:29 thehost peterh: test log message
```

Where "thehost" is the hostname of the server, and "peterh" is the user name below I gave the command.

Now what I want: *I want to collect the log entries of a specific user into a specific file with the syslog-ng*.

The bad-looking, but sometimes working features of the syslog-ng to filter the whole log entry didn't work:

```
# Doesn't work - it doesn't do anything
filter f_peterh { match('peterh'); };
destination d_filter { file("/var/log/peterh.log"); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_peterh); destination(d_peterh); };
```

The documentation available manywhere on the net talk about everything from the binary format of the log messages until the related RFCs, except that *how can I filter the syslog for user names*.

How to do it?

Comment: Logger puts your username in for where the daemon usually goes. Are you looking to capture people who are running logger (and not overriding the username)?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes. Actually, I want to run a wonderful software capable to log only to stdout/stderr, on a way that it runs as a daemon and I see its output in the syslog. To do that, I am wrapping it with a script, pipe its output to a `logger` command, and run this script as a daemon. The daemon will run as a specific user, this user exists only for this daemon. Now I want to separate its log entries into its file. If I could filter for the user, it would be a very nice and simple setting in the syslog-ng - but the syslog-ng documentation is a little bit cloudy, unfortunately.

Comment: @JeffSchaller (simply redirecting the output of the daemon into a logfile is a no-go, there is also a network logging and an alarm/security watch system behind that, and anyways I see no reason to do something sub-optimally because a good software with a trash doc).

Comment: it seems to me that you'd have to `match()` against the `MESSAGE`, unless `MSGHDR` contains more than [rfc3164 specifies as the header](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3164#page-10) , since I don't (yet) see syslog-ng support for [rfc5424's APP-NAME](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5424#page-14)

Comment: @JeffSchaller Probably this should be reached, however the question is, how could I make syslog-ng to filter for that? The basic "match" filter won't work, but if syslog-ng can write this into the syslog, then it surely should be able to also filter for that. But how? The syslog-ng doc talks about everything, except that.

Comment: I would expect `filter f_peterh { match("peterh:", value("MESSAGE")); }` to do it; if not, try dropping the trailing colon in `peterh:` -- I was trying to avoid false positives where other daemons would emit something like `systemd: Starting session ... user peterh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is still on going for you, but for reference for anyone else trying to filter by username, this is how I was able to do it.

I created the following filter.

```
filter sampleUserFilter {
        facility (user) and match ("myUser" value ("PROGRAM"));
};
```

That allowed me to route messages from a specific user (using logger) to a separate file.